# How to reference a Qt Application?

Tags: qt, unit-testing, dll, visual-studio-2013, linker-errors

In order to test some functions of a Qt application (named qtapp), I build the Qt application as lib/dll library. The ctor and dtor have been correctly exported in the library. However compiling the test project (a Qt console project named consoleTest) is always running to the following link errors:

> Link:
>   1>     Bibliothek "C:\Users\gmbh\test\x64\Debug\consoleTest.lib" und Objekt C:\Users\gmbh\test\x64\Debug\consoleTest.exp" werden erstellt.
>   1>moc_testFour.obj : error LNK2001: Nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""public: static struct QMetaObject const qtapp::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@qtapp@@2UQMetaObject@@B)".
>   1>testFour.obj : error LNK2001: Nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""public: static struct QMetaObject const qtapp::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@qtapp@@2UQMetaObject@@B)".
>   1>C:\Users\gmbh\test\x64\Debug\consoleTest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 nicht aufgelöste Externe

The Qt application is quite simple:

```
#ifndef QTAPP_H
#define QTAPP_H

#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include "ui_qtapp.h"

class __declspec(dllexport) qtapp : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    qtapp(QWidget* parent = 0);
    ~qtapp();

private:
    Ui::qtappClass ui;
};

#endif // QTAPP_H
```

Implementation:

```
#include "qtapp.h"

__declspec(dllexport) qtapp::qtapp(QWidget* parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
}

__declspec(dllexport) qtapp::~qtapp()
{

}
```

If I simply include `#include "qtapp.h"` in the test project, the compiler yields the above error.

My questions:

- What are the causes for the errors?
- How to correctly deploy a Qt
  application as lib?

My compiler is visual studio 2013, qt has the version of 5.4.2

Answer (score 1):

That's actually a question independent of Qt. When linking an application against the library you need to have `__declspec(dllimport)` instead of `__declspec(dllexport)`.

To achieve that, one usually uses defines that change when linking the library vs linking the application against the library. Microsoft has a help page on that ["Importing into an Application Using __declspec(dllimport)"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fskxacy(v=vs.80).aspx).

The [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sharedlibrary.html) provides another one. The one thing where Qt can help, is replacing the `__declspec` by a cross-platform [Q_DECL_IMPORT](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#Q_DECL_IMPORT).

Comment: I think, you don't understand my purpose. The above qtapp is actually a dummy project. My final goal is to test some functions in my qt application. At that rate the Qt application should be first **exported** in a dll, which later in my test project will be **imported** and the wanted dll functions will be called and verified.

Comment: With you example code, when you include `qtapp.h` in your test project, it will see a wrong `__declspec(dllexport)` instead of `__declspec(dllimport)`. I can't tell what else might be wrong without a more complete example ;)